# Apply coupon from an affiliate link to ubercart

Tags: ubercart

Modules involved

1. Cart Links
2. uc_discounts_alt or uc_coupon (I like uc_discounts_alt better)
3. uc_affiliate2
4. Ubercart

I need to give the ability to have a coupon applied to the cart if the user came through an affiliate link.

Example:

I have a coupon giving 10% off to "Product 1".  I have a partner "Affiliate 1".

I have a link http://site.com/affiliate/1/cart/add/p1?destination=cart/checkout (which there is an issue there since the destination is redirected before the add to cart is applied)

I want to make it so that when that link is followed the coupon is added to the order.

I figured to do this with Conditional Actions, but the predicates/conditions/actions don't seem to exist.

I guess I need to build a predicate for "Item aded to cart", a condition of "Is there an affiliate" does seem to exist, an action for "Add discount".  But I also seem to need something to tie discounts to affiliates.

Any ideas on how to proceed here?  Are there any modules out there for this?  Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Try [ECO (Extra Customization Options for Ubercart)](http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_eco).

> ECO (Extra Customization Options for Ubercart) provides additional ("extra") options to customize Ubercart.
>
> Some of the functionality provided also includes a degree of integration with other contributed modules like Legal, Webform, and Ubercart Discount Coupons. Among the customization options are using URL parameters to auto-apply coupons in checkout, requiring new customers to choose a password, and integration with the Webform module to pre-populate address fields in checkout.